# d3fc: passing different data to rendering methods

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, webgl, d3fc

Trying to adapt [this](https://d3fc.io/examples/webgl-with-svg-overlay/) example. With a slight difference: i have a bit more of WebGL data and, therefore, do not want to pass it to the SVG renderer at all. SVG renderer should only get one datapoint, but this changes constantly as user moves the mouse. Is it possible to have a switch function that would basically act as a junction and pass two completely different arrays to each of `svgPlotArea()` and `webglPlotArea()` on the same plot?

A simplified original snippet one plot and two rendering functions:

```js
const rand = d3.randomInt(0, 100);

const data = d3.range(100).map(d => ({
  x: rand(),
  y: rand()
}));

data[50].hover = true;

let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 100]);

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 100]);

let webglSeries = fc.seriesWebglPoint()
  .crossValue(d => d.x)
  .mainValue(d => d.y)
  .type(d3.symbolCircle)
  .defined(() => true)
  .size(() => 100)
  .equals((prevData) => prevData.length);

let svgSeries = fc.seriesSvgPoint()
  .crossValue(d => d.x)
  .mainValue(d => d.y)
  .size(() => 300)
  .type(d3.symbolStar)
  .defined((d) => d.hover);

let chart = fc.chartCartesian(xScale, yScale)
  .webglPlotArea(webglSeries)
  .svgPlotArea(svgSeries);


function render() {
  d3.select("div")
    .datum(data)
    .call(chart);
}

render();
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3fc"></script>


<div>
</div>
```

A dirty hack snippet with two independent plots on top of each other and separate data:

```js
const rand = d3.randomInt(0, 100);

const big_data = d3.range(100).map(d => ({
  x: rand(),
  y: rand()
}));

const hover_data = [{
  x: 27,
  y: 11
}, ];

let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 100]);

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 100]);

let webglSeries = fc.seriesWebglPoint()
  .crossValue(d => d.x)
  .mainValue(d => d.y)
  .type(d3.symbolCircle)
  .defined(() => true)
  .size(() => 100)
  .equals((prevData) => prevData.length);

let svgSeries = fc.seriesSvgPoint()
  .crossValue(d => d.x)
  .mainValue(d => d.y)
  .size(() => 300)
  .type(d3.symbolStar)
  .defined(() => true);

let glchart = fc.chartCartesian(xScale, yScale)
  .webglPlotArea(webglSeries);

let svgchart = fc.chartCartesian(xScale, yScale)
  .svgPlotArea(svgSeries);

function render() {
  d3.select("#gl")
    .datum(big_data)
    .call(glchart);

  d3.select("#svg")
    .datum(hover_data)
    .call(svgchart);
}

render();
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3fc"></script>


<div>
  <div id="gl">
  </div>
  <div id="svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a better way, something like pseudocode below?

```
const chart = d3fc.chartCartesian(xScale, yScale)
                  .svgPlotArea(svgSeries)
                  .webglPlotArea(webglSeries)

d3.select( "div" )
  .datum( function() { return whichRenderer ? data1 : data2 } )
  .call(chart);
```

Comment: So what you mean is that, when the mouse moves, the `svgRenderer` should be called, but the `webglRender` should not?

Comment: no, can and should be called, i do not mind as the BIG data does not change on mousemove. i want to avoid skimming through BIG data in order to get 1 hovered element

Comment: i have found out that it's possible within same renderer, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@d3fc/d3fc-series#multi-series , is it possible across different renderers, probably not?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. When I remove the `webglSeries`, render, than add it again, the webgl content is removed during the render

Comment: thanks Ruben, i have learned SO snippets now :)

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be quite possible by using fc.seriesSvgMulti(), see the snippet. In the console, only one node is processed by svgPlotArea's defined() function

```js
let rand = d3.randomInt(0,100);

let data = d3.range(100).map(d => ({
    x: rand(),
    y: rand()
}));

let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, 100])
               .range([0, 100]);

let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, 100])
               .range([0, 100]);

let webglSeries = fc.seriesWebglPoint()
                 .crossValue(d => d.x)
                 .mainValue(d => d.y)
                 .type(d3.symbolCircle)
                 .defined( () => true )
                 .size( () => 100 )
                 .equals( (prevData) => prevData.length );

let svgSeries = fc.seriesSvgPoint()
                 .crossValue(d => d.x)
                 .mainValue(d => d.y)
                 .size( () => 300 )
                 .type(d3.symbolStar)
                 .defined( (d) => { console.log("node check"); return true } );

let multi = fc.seriesSvgMulti()
                .series([svgSeries])
                 .mapping((data, index, series) => {
                     switch (series[index]) {
                         case svgSeries:
                             return getSingleNode();
                     }
                 });

let chart = fc.chartCartesian(xScale, yScale)
    .webglPlotArea(webglSeries)
    .svgPlotArea(multi);

function getSingleNode() {
  return [data[rand()]]
}

function render() {
  d3.select( "div" )
    .datum( data )
    .call(chart);
}

render();
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3fc"></script>

<div>
</div>
```